# Adding rows of data by name and dates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am trying to create a script in Google Apps Script that adds up everyones hours for the day. It goes off the date they did their work and there name. An example of the data is below.

[image: List of data]

So my problem is adding peoples hours on multiple days. So for Karen on the 27th she would have had 4 hours and on the 26th also 4 hours. But I'm not sure how to separate each person out into times like that. It could just be done manually but I am trying to automate it.

This is the code I have currently got:

```
function compare() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var jiraSheet = ss.getSheetByName("NEWDATA");
  var jiraRows = jiraSheet.getLastRow();
  var tsRows = tsSheet.getLastRow();

  var harvestData = tsSheet.getRange("A2:D"+tsRows).getValues();
  var jiraData = jiraSheet.getRange("C2:F"+jiraRows).getValues();
  for(var x = 0; x < (jiraRows-1); x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < (jiraRows -1); y++) {
      if(jiraData[x][3] == jiraData[y][3] && Utilities.formatDate(jiraData[x][1], "GMT", "DD-MM-YYY") == Utilities.formatDate(jiraData[y][1], "GMT", "DD-MM-YYY")) {


      } else if(y == (jiraRows - 2)){

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you just need aggregate (sum) time for each user by date. Is username unique key? And do you need change existing sheet or you can put calculated into another one?

Comment: Use an associative `Object` to store key-value pairs, such as an employee id with a value that is an object of dates and aggregated time, e.g. `{8675309: {name: "Jenny Smith", dates: {"1970-01-01": 5.3, "1970-01-02": 4.25, ... }}, 5553895: {name: "Jane Doe", dates: { ...} }, ... }`. You'd build that object by stepping through your array of data, and then to write your report, you'd step through that object (rather than the input array).

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to use google script but I personally wouldn't bother as you can generate a unique list of names (Bob, Karen..etc) using the UNIQUE(C1:C) function in google sheets.  You can then generate a range of dates by entering a start date and using a formula to increment it as far as required.  All you need then is a sumifs formula to populate the hours.

[image: Get hours screenshot]

I did this in Excel but I'll share a Sheets version if you're interested.  Different layouts can also be automated.  You could also use a pivot table or a Query formula to create somthing similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Table in screenshot is A2:C25, Try D1:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"Select C,B,sum(A) group by C,B",1)
```